# Format output in python and Flask

Tags: python, flask

I finally got the data to show in my browser however the issue I have a bit is how that data is displayed and the only thing I can do at the moment is create a new line. I am trying to actually put stuff into seperated line.

My flask code

```
from __future__ import print_function
import flask
from myoptimizer_optimizer import Site, Sport, get_optimizer
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/yield')
def index():
    def inner():
        optimizer = get_optimizer(Site.SomeSite, Sport.SomeSport)
        optimizer.load_players_from_CSV("/myssdvfile.csv")
        player = optimizer.players[0]  # get random player from optimizer players
        player.max_exposure = 0.5
        lineup_generator = optimizer.optimize(3)
        for lineup in lineup_generator:
            yield '%s</br>\n' % lineup
    return flask.Response(inner(), mimetype='text/html')  # text/html is required for most browsers to show the partial page immediately

app.run(debug=True)
```

This returns info like this
1. Player1 Position Points 2. Player2 Position Points....

It does this 5 times in a row.. However I am trying to put something like:

```
1.Player1 Position Points
2.Player2 Position Points
-------------------------
Next generated lines
1.Player1 Position Points
2.Player2 Position Points
```

I have NO idea on how to separate the players. With Print and No flask it comes out just like I explained above.. but with Flask.. I just don't know how to format the text like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def inner():
    ...
    output = optimizer.optimize(3)
    return output

return flask.Response('\n'.join(inner()), mimetype='text/html')
```

Comment: Thank you , that worked for making lines individual.. although now players are still in one row.. like 1. player1 55 55, player2 22 22, player3 66 66